# Plot an SCNNode in a ARSCNVIEW irespective of the Camera's position

Tags: ios, iphone, scenekit, arkit

I am developing an iOS in-store navigation app for a retail store using AR Scene Kit which should resembles as [Lowe's Vision Navigation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lowes.vision.nav&hl=en). Hence, At first I want to programatically plot the position of any xyz product which is available in the store in an AR Scene Kit irrespective of the camera's initial position, but the position of the Product will remain same in the Store. I was totally new to AR as well as Scene Kit.

I am able to add a SCNNode in the ARSCNView but the problem will be  my camera's initial position according to that only the SCNNode is plotting. Once this is done, then I need to give the in-store navigation for the selected product from my position inside the store may be using iBeacon or other equivalent.

Comment: You can use imageDetection to get initial position.

Answer (score 0):

SCNNodes operate somewhat like UIViews, in the sense that, as you said, the positions are relative to the parent node/view. For the cases where you want the position relative to the whole view or the world you can use worldTransform and -convertPosition:toNode: .

[World Transform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNNode/worldTransform)

[Convert Position To Node](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNNode/convertPosition:toNode:)